# Why is information gain rarely used as a reported effect size?

Tags: effect-size, information-theory, odds-ratio, confusion-matrix, relative-risk

Commonly, in reporting effect sizes in medical articles, papers typically report: risk difference (RD), relative risk (RR) and odds ratio (OR) (and for variable timescale cases and other situations, proportional hazard CPH, which I'll ignore for this).

By contrast, machine learning methods looking to maximize discrimination between groups may optimize information gain (IG), or information gain ratio IGR (e.g. most methods employing decision trees). In ML, this is *strongly* the favorite measure of group difference.

Each of these methods are simply group difference effect size scores (scores of a confusion matrix) and can be all applied in the same scenarios to detect 'surprise'. Hypothesis: RD, RR, OR are less commonly used in ML for decision tree building because they are less effective at building models in out-of-sample tests. (Is it true? I *assume*, so.)

Question: Why are IG, IGR not popular measures of group discrimination in reporting? (Notably its not mentioned once in this book: [https://www.amazon.com/Essential-Guide-Effect-Sizes-Interpretation/dp/0521142466](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521142466))

Comment: Some initial questions you might ponder that hint that the answer. First, does information gain capture the direction of effect? Why, in a medical trial, would this be of fundamental importance? Second, does a huge effect size necessarily translate into high predictive power? In education, for instance, an intervention that moved outcomes by 0.2 standard deviations would be considered quite good. What would the $R^2$ from such an effect approximately be assuming a normally distributed baseline, constant treatment effects, and a 50/50 split between treatment and control?

Comment: By the way, my second point was made in terms of $R^2$. Let me pre-empt any potential objections that you were asking about information gain specifically by saying that either is a pure measure of predictive power, and the point I’m trying to make more generally is that predictive power does not map very neatly in what clinical trials care about. I frame the question in terms of $R^2$ because it is relatively easy to calculate in my example.

Comment: A third point that occurred to me: is information gain invariant to setting? Suppose, for instance, that we find that a medical treatment was found to work very well in an experiment with a 50/50 treatment/control split. Suppose, afterwards, we find out that we actually have a whole other control population we could compare to, so we add them to the control group. What would happen to information gain? Is it fair to interpret this change as reflecting a change in the medicine’s effectiveness?

Comment: Re: direction of effect, invariance to setting, invariance to prevalence, some small effects are significant in my domain, ...: IG seems no different from most effect measures in this respect - most have downsides.
I guess my question is less about application areas specifically, but rather, if ML practice has settled upon IG as being a consistently good discriminator, why is not used as an effect measure generally? Alternatively, I could ask If you believe other effect measures are what you want, why aren't we directly optimizing for them over IG in decision tree implementations?

Comment: Perhaps I was not clear in my answer: my point is not that IG is never the right thing to do, just that it is *not always* the right thing to do. As you correctly point out, this is true of RD, RR, or OR as well: each is suited to a particular application.

Comment: In ML, the question is often something like "my data is complex, and I want to adapt my model predictions to best fit this complexity". In that case, IG is a great way to summarize the extent to which the model is working. In many medical settings, the problem is "my data is simple, and I want to ask a simple question of it like if the drug had a positive effect as intended". In this case, IG may still have some relation to the question at hand (e.g. big effects in either direction likely have big IG), but it more direct to just report the quantity of interest in the first place.

Comment: There is also an intermediate case. Sometimes (observational studies), there is no experiment, so the data is not so simple. Here, in order to answer the simple question of "what is the effect of the intervention", one has to, as prerequisite, answer the complex question "how do I best fit the complexity of the data". In this case, it is a good idea to also report IG to show that the prerequisite is satisfied. Nonetheless the bottom line question the researcher cares about is "what is the effect", so it is unsurprising that the headline number will still be some measure of effect, not of IG.